# how add microsoft.office.interop.word (2003 Version) in VS 2010

Tags: c#, ms-word, primary-interop-assembly

I Want Add Office 2003 Primary Interop Assemblies to Visual Studio.
so i following this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa159923(v=office.11).aspx

but i find just Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word For Version 12.0.0.0 (For Office 2007) And Version 14.0.0.0 (For Office 2010). And Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word For Office 2003 Version Does Not Exist in My VS Library.

I Also Install Office 2003 Update: Redistributable Primary Interop Assemblies From Under Link But Doesn't Difference.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20923

How Solve My Problem?

Comment: Do you have Office 2003 installed on the computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Interop the office assembly, you need to install the office on the machine. You have installed Office 2007 and 2010 on your machine, so you are not able to find office 2007 version assemblies in reference.

But you can install the runtime for interop and do the task.

[How to Install Office Primary Interop Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 Thats it! Otherwise @mehdi please edit your question to show `how you are looking to add references` in comparison with the folder those references should be in. IF you can show that I'll +1 your question too.